# Create/Load SKTilemapnode without using SKS/Scene files

Tags: sprite-kit, sktilemapnode

I create my sprite kit games programmatically and the sks files end up just confusing me.

Is there a way to load or create a tile map node without having to use the sks/scene file?

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39533705/programmatically-create-sktilemapnode-in-swift/39544119#39544119) discusses how to create the map with an existing tileset created in the editor.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41352251/what-is-the-proper-way-to-programmatically-create-a-spritekit-sktilemap/41434435#41434435) discusses how to create both tileset and map.

Comment: I figured out a way to do it, first add this extension:

Comment: if you add your solution as an answer, you might get the `Self Learner` badge!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a way to to do it:

- 1) Create a SKS file called tilemaps
- 2) Create all your maps in there
- 3) Add this extension to load that scene file in your current scene:

  ```
  extension SKNode {
  class func unarchiveFromFile(file : NSString) -> SKNode? {
      if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: file as String, ofType: "sks") {
          let sceneData = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

          let archiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: sceneData as! Data)

          archiver.setClass(self.classForKeyedUnarchiver(), forClassName: "SKScene")
          let scene = archiver.decodeObject(forKey: NSKeyedArchiveRootObjectKey) as! SKNode
          archiver.finishDecoding()
          return scene
      } else {
          return nil
      }
  }
  ```

  }

Then grab the tile map from the sks file. Weird trick is that you have to remove it from its parent first:

```
    guard 
      let tileScene = SKScene.unarchiveFromFile(file: "TileMaps"),
      let testMap = tileScene.childNode(withName: "Dungeon1")
        as? SKTileMapNode else {
            fatalError("Background node not loaded")
    }
    self.testMap = testMap
    self.testMap.removeFromParent()
    self.testMap.zPosition = 1200

    self.addChild(testMap)
```